# What airspaces are the Florida Everglades?

Tags: airspace

If I'm flying through the Florida Everglades, what airspace would it be?

Comment: It depends on your location and altitude. You can find any of the classes of airspace above the Everglades.

Answer (score 1):

The Florida Everglades covers a vast area.

([link](https://skyvector.com/?ll=25.966317174055224,-80.70906829217046&chart=301&zoom=1))

I found parts of it are within Class Bravo, Class Charlie and Class Delta, Class Echo, and Class Gulf.

Comment: And if you go high enough, Class A.